# Do you need to "commit" between multiple oracle sql executions in a c# app?

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

```
 var oraConnectionString = new OracleConnectionStringBuilder(_connectionString);
            using (var oraConnection = new OracleConnection(oraConnectionString.ConnectionString))
            {
                oraConnection.Open();
                try
                {
                    using (var command = new OracleCommand(sqlText, oraConnection))
                    {
                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                        command.BindByName = true;
                        command.Parameters.Add("node", _currentNode);
                        command.Parameters.Add("carrierId", CarrierId);
                        command.Connection.BeginTransaction();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.CommandText = UtilityMethods.LoadTemplate("Resources/CreateCarrier.sql", "Carriers");
                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                        command.Parameters.Add("carrierName", CarrierName);
                        command.Parameters.Add("line1", Line1);
                        command.Parameters.Add("line2", Line2);
                        command.Parameters.Add("line3", Line3);
                        command.Parameters.Add("line4", Line4);
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.CommandText = UtilityMethods.LoadTemplate("Resources/GetCarrierId.sql", "Carriers");
                        CarrierId = Convert.ToString(command.ExecuteScalar());
                        if (CarrierId == null)
                        {
                            //TODO
                        }

                        command.Parameters.Clear();
                        command.CommandText = command.CommandText = UtilityMethods.LoadTemplate("Resources/AddCarrierToNode.sql", "Carriers");
                        command.Parameters.Add("node", _currentNode);
                        command.Parameters.Add("rank", Convert.ToInt32(Rank));
                        command.Parameters.Add("carrierId", Convert.ToInt32(CarrierId));
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.Transaction.Commit();
                    }
                }
```

For some reason CarrierId is returning null. The only thing that I can think of is that the changes from the previous sql commands have not been committed. Can anyone please tell me if you need to commit between each execution?

Comment: Since we cannot see what you SQL commands are, how do you know that is not the issue in there?

Comment: Within an Oracle session, one commit is enough to save DML operation done prior to that commit.

Comment: When to commit should be dictated exclusively by the business logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends...

1. If you use the ODBC connection, you should check the settings for this link. By default, ODBC connection doesn't request autocommit for every operation.
2. I recommend you to call "Commit" after your operation anytime. You should implement your business logic in program and don't wait the potential configuration issue in ODBC configuration or other environment.

Comment: Nope - "By default, ODBC transactions are in **auto-commit mode**" -https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms714549(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Sorry, I mixed the sqlplus environment and ODBC settings.

However, user / administrator can change it and I recommend to call "Commit" after all critical operation in the code.